# Mootools Autocomplete

Tags: ruby-on-rails, autocomplete, mootools, autosuggest

Does anyone know of a plugin script for mootools autocompete?

[Digitarald](http://digitarald.de/project/autocompleter/) is throwing loads of errors such as:

```
input.substr is not a function
[Break On This Error] if (input.substr(0, start).toLowerCa...queryValue.toLowerCase()) start = 0;
```

[Meio](http://www.meiocodigo.com/projects/meio-autocomplete/) I cannot get to work with a url/json request. it is throwing a strange test is not a function error.

I have tried others but nothing works.
I am using mootools because of Fancy upload.
Any help would be really great.

s

Comment: I will be releasing one that I use within a couple weeks should I pm an early look at it?

Comment: all he needs to do is go to the mootools forge. things like meio autocomplete by fabio miranda costa of the mootools-core team come to mind.

Comment: Could you please create a jsfiddle.net showing the error?
TY

Answer (score 0):

What version of moo tools are you using?

I believe digitaralds is based on 1.2, so if you have downloaded 1.4 you will want to make sure to include compatibility in your download package.

Also make sure that you are have any and all moo more that is required with his autocompleter